# Postgresql query between two tables returns multiple entries for one Id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to make a query that links the name of the client that's on the client table to the cargo that has the corresponding id. I'm doing this query:

```
SELECT c.id, c.status, c.client_id, c.dt, c.cargo_date, c.cargo_hour, c.origin, c.destination, c.code_name, c.download_at, c.download_hour, c.weight, c.ramp_id, c.truck_id, c.driver_id, c.cargo_return, c.returning, c.description, cl.name, cl.id 
from cargos c, 
     clients cl 
where c.status = 'planner' and (c.destination != 'SANTIAGO') 
  or  (c.destination = 'SANTIAGO' and c.returning is not NULL) 
 AND  c.client_id = cl.id 
order by COALESCE(c.returning, c.id);
```

but when I do that it returns me each cargo with every client in my client's table, isn't the AND  c.client_id = cl.id supposed to make the result unique per id?

Comment: Pleaser provide sample data, desired results and a clear explanation of the logic.  Also learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be missing brackets around one of your AND statements to include one of the OR's AND all the others:

So you do status AND one or the other in the brackets I added, AND Client_id = cl.ID

When you use AND and OR in your where clause you have to make sure you put braces around the groups you want or else it can really mess up your logic.

```
where 
c.status = 'planner' 
and 
    -- I added the opening and closing bradckets around the OR statement
    (
        (c.destination != 'SANTIAGO') 
        or (c.destination = 'SANTIAGO' and c.returning is not NULL) 
    )
AND c.client_id = cl.id
```